# ¿Por qué no me funciona una clase en una etiqueta html <a>?

Tags: html5, css3

```
<li class="main-icon">
     <a href="#"></a>
</li>
```

Mi duda es que al utilizar código CSS en esa clase "main-icon" sí me funciona si la clase está declarada en la etiqueta `<li>` pero no me funciona si la declaro en la etiqueta `<a>`.

¿A qué se debe?

Comment: ¿Que estilos aplica dicha clase?, por que al momento te diría que es debido a que la etiqueta esta vacía

Comment: Indica el código CSS de toda la clase, así podríamos ver el error, algo común, puede ser que main-cion está definido solo en el li como `li.main-icon` o que el estilo funcione bien en bloques `display:block` y `a` no tenga ese estilo de bloque.